# c++, change pointer of a object inside another class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I need to change the pointer of a object inside a class.
In this example I would like the call from the member function of b b->getBase(); in the main prints the value 2, and not 1.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
base *b = new base(1);
top *t = new top( b);
b->getBase();
return 0;
}
```

base.h

```
class base
{
public:
    base(int _x);
    void getBase();
private :
    int x;
};
```

base.cpp

```
base::base(int _x):x(_x)
{
cout <<"base constructor:"<<x<<":";
};

void base::getBase()
{
cout <<"getBase()"<< x<< endl;
}
```

top.h

```
class top
{
public:
    top(base *b);
private:
    int topVar;
    base * b;
};
```

top.cpp

```
top::top(base * _b):b(_b)
{
    b->getBase();
    b = new base(2);
    b->getBase();
}
```

Results:
    base constructor:1
    getBase():1
    base constructor:2
    getBase():2
    getBase():1

Comment: Pass a _reference_ to a pointer: `top::top(base*& b)`, so that the pointer in `main` changes too? Although a very strange thing to do...

Comment: Marked as dupe since that other question and it's accepted answer combined provide an answer to this one.

Comment: And some other things to change, mainly you need to change `_b`, not `b` in `top::top()`.

Comment: It works if I use :
top::top(base *& b):b(b)
but it does not work if I use:
top::top(base *& _b):b(_b)
why does is happen?